# AWS Lambda: Get Sales

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm very new on AWS and I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to get the sales of my Amazon Store using AWS Lambda.

The goal is to create the function that returns an object with the store sales and that it can be requested via API.

I have been looking around for this information or any tutorial without any luck.

I would thank you guys for any information on the matter and sorry for the general question.

Comment: Does the Amazon Store (I have never worked with that) expose an API?

Comment: I'm exploring that myself. I think I have found something here: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/fba-inventory-api/fbaInventory.md
It is for amazon FBA which is my case, but still exploring this

Comment: Assume it does have an API, you can write Lambda function that wraps that API call. For example, if it exposes a Java API, you can use that in a Lambda function created using the Lambda Java runtime API.